# iOS7 and iOS8 UI Frame issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, ios8, size-classes

I have a slightly extensive UI where I have to place different views one below the other. So I've created each view as a separate `UIView` class and pasted them one below the other onto a `UIViewController`.

The issue I'm facing is that the frame of the `UIViews` are different in `iOS7` and `iOS8`. `iOS7` works the way I want it.

[image] || [image]

The first screenshot is from iOS8 and the second is from iOS7. I specifically provided the height while adding the views as well like so:

```
UIViewController *test = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GeneralMatchInfoViewController"];
_generalMatchFrame = test.view.frame;
_generalMatchFrame.origin.x = 10.0f;
_generalMatchFrame.size.width = self.scrollBaseView.frame.size.width - 20.0f;
_generalMatchFrame.size.height = 255.0f;
test.view.frame = _generalMatchFrame;
[self addChildViewController:test];
[self.scrollBaseView addSubview:test.view];
[test didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

`iOS7` adjusts perfectly, having 10 pixels from the left and setting the frame correctly. But on `iOS8`, the frame size is not 255. I'm using size class. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try to add constraints.

Comment: @KathiravanG Like I mentioned, I'm using size class

Comment: I also have same issue? Do you find the answer?